# Show scroll bar in Internet Explorer for ignored class

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll, microsoft-edge

In Internet Explorer and Edge, I am trying to hide all scrollbars on elements with overflow, except for elements with a specific class:

```
*:not(.ignore-scrollbar-rule) {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

However, I cannot get this rule to apply, and the scrollbar is hidden even on elements with the class `ignore-scrollbar-rule`. Is there a reason this rule is ignored in IE/Edge?

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvLpvtop/1/)

Comment: Are sure you don't have any other overflow rules conflicting here? If it hides *all* scrollbars there are only two options: the class is wrong and not the same in CSS and HTML, or there is another rule that is hiding the scrollbars where they shouldn't. What does the code inspector say?

Comment: @BramVanroy, I included a JS Fiddle with the most basic issue present. I will have to keep looking. But in that example, there is nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in Internet Explorer, you can't use `:not(...)`. You need to have two separate selectors. One that targets everything, and another that targets the one (className).

```
* {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.ignore-scrollbar-rule {
    -ms-overflow-style: auto;
}
```

Now the `.ignore-scrollbar-rule` rule can be applied to whatever element you want independant of its hierarchy.

[Fiddle to try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/hvLpvtop/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the problem seems to be that the rule also applies to the inner element (as it should because you assign it to all elements) and for some reason the property then bubbles up, or is at least wrongly interpreted by Edge. Seems like a bug to me. You can by-pass it by only selecting the outer classes, [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/hvLpvtop/2/).

```
.outer:not(.ignore-scrollbar-rule) {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Quick question then about this. So that class has the potential to be used on any element, and writing CSS for each possible element would be impossible, which is why it was prefixed with `*`. I'm assuming I may be out of luck to do something like that?

Comment: @KevBot I thought you would. I've been trying some stuff out but cannot find a solution. I'd advise you to wait and maybe some one else can come up with a solution. This is an interesting problem. In a couple of days you may want to start a bounty of 50 on this question to draw attention.